# Using node and node-phantom to scrape AngularJS Application

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have a node script set up to scrape pages from an AngularJS application and then generate code needed for testing purposes. It works great except for one thing. ng-if. Since ng-if removes elements from the dom the script never sees these blocks of code. I can't remove the ng-if's. So I'm wondering if there is some way to intercept the html between when node-phantom requests the page and when it actually loads everything in to phantoms dom. What I'm hoping to do is simply set all the ng-if's to true so that all content is available. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

*EDIT* I'm using phantomjs-node not node-phantom.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample page so that I could use it in an example?

Comment: @Vaviloff - I'm not sure what you want as an example.... could you be more specific? if you just want an example of using ng-if then http://plnkr.co/edit/UdT7mfG9P7mWmK7g2L4G?p=preview

Comment: Why do you want to "intercept" it? Why can't you write a scraper in the same way as a user would navigate the site?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm scraping content to generate Page Object Models for Selenium and Appium, our automated testing tools. The purpose is to speed up the process of creating the automated tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Final solution was to scrape the page for all of the comment tags. Then filter through to find the ones that contained ng-ifs and parse out variable names from those tags. Then I tapped into Angular's $scope and set all of the variables to true. Forcing everything that is hidden on the page to be visible.